# Choosing coordinate system for mapping Mars in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, basemap

I wish to use ArcGIS Desktop to map planets, in particular Mars.

Where would I start in terms of basemapping and projection?

Comment: A google on "ArcGIS mars coordinate reference" returned a link to http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_coordinate_systems.pdf Non-earth spheroids start at the bottom of page 2.

Comment: thanks you @Vince. Where can I find these projections as something I can impot to ArcGIS?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an intrinsic feature of ArcGIS.  Just open "Geographic Coordinate Systems" folder, then the "Solar System" folder, then choose "Mars" and the datum associated with your data.

[image]

Comment: Note: ArcGIS doesn't have any projected coordinate reference systems for the other planets and moons. If you want to use a projected CRS, you'll have to make a custom one.

Comment: Can it be called a 'Geographic' coordinate system though as s.s. geography is the study of the Earth?