# Visualizing SAR images of moon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, georeferencing, moon

I have SAR images of a region on the Moon in GeoTIFF format.

When opened in ArcMap, an image looks like:

[image]

With the metadata:

[image]    [image]

How can I geo-reference them to visualize properly?

I also have an Excel sheet with the lat/long info of all the pixels, can it be used ?

[image]

Update1:

I tried using the "project raster" for projecting it to GCS_Moon_2000 with following parameters:

[image]

But the following error is coming

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing coordinate system for mapping Mars in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179474/choosing-coordinate-system-for-mapping-mars-in-arcgis-desktop)

Comment: https://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_coordinate_systems.pdf

Comment: I tried projecting the raster in "GCS_Moon_2000", as given in the pdf above. But it shows error (Updated in the question).

Comment: Try to use `Define Projection` instaed of `Project raster` https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/define-projection.htm

Comment: Tried that, results are still looking the same. Only change is in the metadata, which shows the new defined projection